# What algorithm is used to generate nonce hash in genesis file?

Tags: nonce, genesis

When looking for information about the nonce property of the genesis file, everything says that it is a `64-bit string hash` etc.

But which algorithm is used to generate this hash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really no hashing involved in this nonce, the value is arbitrary and the definition "64-bit string hash" is misleading, IMHO.

A better definition for nonce in this specific context can be found in the [Ethereum Yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (page 5, top right). There, the nonce is defined as "A 64-bit value (...)".

It's actually just any value between 0 and 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The nonce itself is just a number represented in hexadecimal format.